# Use AWK to filter files that have 0 value

Tags: filter, awk

My file contains 36 columns (tab-delimited), the first 4 columns contain names and identification info, the remaining 32 columns contain float numbers (double or 0). I want to filter out those rows that have 0 values in in the last 32 columns (also tab-delimited in the output file).

I am thinking about using this :

```
if ($5 != 0 && $6 !=0 && ..... $36 != 0) {print $0}
```

But this looks so ugly and I guess the efficiency is not high given the fact that there're 32 conditions in the if statement. Is there any efficient way to get the job done? thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `for` loop:

```
awk '{ for (i=5; i<=NF; i++) { if ($i != 0) { print; next } } }' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short `awk` for you.

```
awk '/[[:space:]].*[1-9]/' file
```